Firefox input range does not work, gives "TypeError: rangeNode is null"
I am creating a webpage with a slider, and it works on other browsers on mobile and desktop. But on firefox, the slider does not work no matter what.
Pretty sure this is a problem with firefox itself, because the error message says that the error is in content.js:461:9. No idea how to fix it.
The slider looks like this,
<input type="range" min="1000" max="20000" value="6000" class="slider" id="myslider">

and the code commanding it looks like this
var slider = document.getElementById("myslider");
slider.oninput = function() {
    value = this.value;
    console.log('working')
}

The rangeNode error is a part of the huge content.js. The error is specifically this function, in the first rangeNode.data variable.
if (rangeNode.data && rangeOffset === rangeNode.data.length) {
    rangeNode = findNextTextNode(rangeNode.parentNode, rangeNode);
    rangeOffset = 0;
}

Is there a way to implement the input range on firefox?

how is slider defined?

Please show the code around line 461 of content.js.

I ran this in jsfiddle on Firefox and it worked fine.

The error message clearly says that rangeNode is null. So the problem must be in the code that sets rangeNode.

You seem to be calling rangeNode before defining it.
